# Save a FLV video with Wireshark or ngrep − or whatever

Tags: networking, flv, wireshark, dump, ngrep

There is a FLV video on a webstie that I'd like to save in order to display it offline. I already tried several solutions which didn't work:

- Basically, it's impossible to get the video from the HTML source code. I do know the exact URL of the video, but there is some kind of protection that forbids the same URL to be played again, either in the browser or with wget.
- It's also impossible with Firefox or Chrome tools. Also, it's impossible with tools that looks into the Flash cache directory (I run on Ubuntu), as [flashdownload.sh](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/a-script-to-save-cached-flash-videos-on-linux.html)
- I tried to setup a proxy as squid, but it failed: it seems the foreign website detects it, doesn't accept proxy and it forward me to Google! Also, I'm not sure to understand how to setup correctly squid to save me in the cache directory a playable video file.

Therefore, my clue is to "sniff" the HTTP connection and make a dump of the FLV. I already tried with Wireshark and the option to save HTTP objects in the menu, but unfortunately it doesn't show the FLV file (it shows it if I go to classical video websites). It show me bounce of TCP packets, but my issue is that I'm very unable to reassemble it to one file! Is there any easy solution to do it?

I also tried with ngrep as I am with Ubuntu, but same problem, I have difficulties to find the right command.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Why look into the browser's flash cache directory? Why not just look into chrome's cache directory? Have you tried emptying your browser's cache and playing the video? you should find your file somewhere in the browser's cache(it won't have an extension).

Comment: Actually, there is no such file in the cache directory. The FLV video file is displayed through a SWF/Flash object and my guess is this stuff disables any cache system.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a soft which makes the deal : [TubeMaster++](http://www.tubemaster.net/)

It gives me the FLV file! Unfortunately, the file is unreadable... I suspect some kind of encryption: a key seems to be given to the SWGF player, which then makes the file clear. Unfortunately, no way for me to understand how to do this... The reason I think it's encrypted is because I've no problems with this tool to get other FLV files (Youtube, etc.).

Therefore, I give up this way. The only solution which remains is to capture the video stream with a tool like RecordMyDesktop.

Thanks for your help!